# azure web app display images from mounted blob storage

Tags: azure-web-app-service, azure-blob-storage, blazor-server-side

I have an azure Linux web app with a blob storage mounted that stores images. they are both on the same vnet subnet and I have a private link configured and the webapp returns the private IP when doing a nslookup in the kudu ssh tool.

I have an API controller that uploads just fine using the blob SDK.

I only want my webapp to be able to access the images, but I want to display them in my Blazor server side app. I was thinking that if I referenced the mounted path I could do an image tag like `<img src="/mountedBlob/imageName.png" />` but that returns a 404. I have the blob storaged mounted in two different places. One at the Linux root `/mountedBlob` and another at the wwwroot `/home/site/wwwroot/mountedBlob`

the 404 is returned when I have the anonymous read access set to blobs only. A 403/401 is returned when I disable the anonymous access. I would like this set to private in the end.

My end goal is to display images shared in blob storage that has no anonymous or public access. I'm using Blazor server side. Can I accomplish this with a simple img tag with the blob storage mounted. Or are my options only to go through the storage api/sdk and get the data? Using a user delegated key requires to have the user as a blob data contributor role assigned and that's not feasible for this scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that I need to mount my blob storage to the path`/home/site/wwwroot/wwwroot/mountedblob`